# protobuf-net: Backward compability when type has changed?

Tags: c#, versioning, protobuf-net

is there a way to provide backward compability when a member type has changed? For example, class Person consists in version 1 of one integer, but in version 2 of a string. I know that this is breaking the contract, but the example is an issue that isn't seldom in the real life software development.

Thanks in advance.

```
// Version 1
[ProtoContract]
class Person 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

// Version 2
[ProtoContract]
class Person 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shim property is probably your best bet:

```
// Version 2
[ProtoContract]
class Person 
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private int? ID_v1 {
        get { return null; } // means it won't be serialized
        set { if(value != null) ID = value.ToString(); }
    }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but two questions: 1. Isn't is a contract break when we change the type from 'int' to 'int?' ?  Does that mean that

Comment: <Sorry, forget the first comment, here is the whole one> Thanks a lot, but two questions: 1. Isn't it a contract break when we change the type from 'int' to 'int?' ?  2. There is no serialization of null? I am worry about that there could be a lot of old 'garbage' with the time in my binary file. I have also concerns about deserialization: Even it's ID_v1 is null, it may waste memory, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Guenter 1) no, protobuf-net won't consider `int` <===> `int?` as a contract break, because at the protobuf layer (the wire spec) this is simply an optional `int`; 2) at the protobuf layer, there is no concept of `null` - again, it will simply be treated as an optional value, where the `null` says "don't write this", so it will be *read* if it is in the stream, but it will never be *written*. So it will never take any memory in the stream, and because there is no *field*, it won't take any memory in the object either

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. And congratulations - you are doing an amazing work.